# Can't get data from dataSnapShot in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have checked these and other questions that how to get data from `dataSnapShot` so please first read the question.

- [Can't get value from Firebase Database DataSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968342/cant-get-value-from-firebase-database-datasnapshot)
- [Unable to read data from firebase in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261522/unable-to-read-data-from-firebase-in-android)
- [Read Data From Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800547/read-data-from-firebase-database)

Below is the my Firebase DB structure where I am performing these all.

[image]

I have implemented below code to get/read data from Firebase. **Issue is** unable to get value by using that key or by passing that key directly. When I get key then its possible and printed also but its not working with value.

```
mDatabase!!.reference.child(FirebaseKey.NodeEmpCheckInOut) //-->EmpCheckInOut
            .child(AppConstant.yyyy_MM.format(Date()))     //-->2019-04
            .child(userSession!!.getUserId())              //-->N8OE2CGu8nav0k0n7Rh61tKjvRF3
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(dataSnapshotError: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error:Exception->" + dataSnapshotError.message)
                }

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapShot: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "complete Data SnapShot::->$dataSnapShot")

                    for (dsnpNode: DataSnapshot in dataSnapShot.children) {
                        val key: String = dsnpNode.key.toString()
                        val value: Any? = dsnpNode.child(key).child("checkIn").getValue().toString()

                        //I have tried these ways also to retry data
                        //val value: String = dsnpNode.child(key).child("checkIn").value.toString()
                        //val value: String = dsnpNode.child("2019-04-11").child("checkIn").value.toString()

                        Logg.i(TAG, "key->$key")
                        Logg.i(TAG, "value::-> $value")

                        /*Log value is printed in log window
                          key->2019-04-11
                          value::-> null*/
                    }
                }

            })
```

When i print `dataSnapShot.toString()` then its printed as below in
 log window.

```
{ key = N8OE2CGu8nav0k0n7Rh61tKjvRF3, value = {2019-04-17={todayDate=2019-04-17, checkIn=05:41 AM, isCheckIn=2, checkOut=05:44 PM}, 2019-04-23={todayDate=2019-04-23, checkIn=03:29 PM, isCheckIn=1, checkOut=00}, 2019-04-12={todayDate=2019-04-12, checkIn=09:35 AM, isCheckIn=2, checkOut=10:00 PM}, 2019-04-16={todayDate=2019-04-16, checkIn=05:39 AM, isCheckIn=2, checkOut=05:39 PM}, 2019-04-18={todayDate=2019-04-18, checkIn=05:55 PM, isCheckIn=2, checkOut=08:13 PM}, 2019-04-13={todayDate=2019-04-13, checkIn=09:36 AM, isCheckIn=2, checkOut=5:00 PM}, 2019-04-19={todayDate=2019-04-19, checkIn=10:48 AM, isCheckIn=1, checkOut=00}, 2019-04-11={todayDate=2019-04-11, checkIn=05:35 AM, isCheckIn=2, checkOut=08:00 PM}, 2019-04-22={todayDate=2019-04-22, checkIn=12:10 PM, isCheckIn=1, checkOut=00}} }
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
val key: String = dsnpNode.key.toString()
```

to

```
val key: String = dsnpNode.key
```

Calling `toString()` doesn't help you at all since the keys are always strings.

And also change the following line of code:

```
val value: Any? = dsnpNode.child(key).child("checkIn").getValue().toString()
```

to

```
val value: Any? = dsnpNode.child("checkIn").getValue(String::class.java)
```

See, I have removed the call to `.child(key)` because there is no need for that.

Comment: Thanks, Its working. I just want to know that `checkIn` is child of date node and we don't pass then also its working, how ?

Comment: Simply call `hasChild()` function: `dsnpNode.hasChild("checkIn")`.